# I'm Getting this Trojan Detection Error When Installing Laravel

Tags: laravel, security, windows-defender, trojan

I'm trying to create a new project using "laravel new projectName". During installation it threw this error:

```
...
  - Removing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.0.1)
  - Downgrading vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.2.0 => v4.1.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.1.7): Downloading (100%)

  [ErrorException]
  copy(C:\xampp\htdocs\tweety\vendor/symfony/console/ed95772252371be6fe6d0571b112ce09): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

At the same time, windows (10) defender notified for a Trojan and blocked it.
[Threat Protection History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkobE.png)

I've not installed any unknown software, also scanned the system using Gridin Soft anti-malware but, nothing was found. Would anybody be able to help? I'm stuck.

Comment: sometime antivirus give false alarm, just ignore it, and add it to exception

Comment: okay. I'll try adding exception. Don't know why but it was all fine till yesterday.

Comment: I got the same error: Trojan:Win32/CryptInject!ml

Comment: FYI there's [an open issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/38457)